# Anchor tag isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to make a video in an iframe play automatically and when you click it a third party video player opens up in a lightbox fashion.

I have the video auto playing and want it to be so that when the user clicks the video a lightbox effect comes and shows the video using this third party tool. To invoke the lightbox an anchor tag is used to call the script.

Code:

```
<a href="#OhRW8wN18o4" class="sublime" data-youtube-id="OhRW8wN18o4" data-autoresize="fit">

      <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" wmode="transparent" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OhRW8wN18o4?controls=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</a>
```

Bonus: 
When the user calls the lightbox effect the video continues from the thumbnail position

I am using a sublime video player for this

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you should use YouTube's embed script, and not put the whole page in an iframe. This way you don't have to 'scroll' to the video in the page.